# Web Server: SVN Repository

Tags: svn, webserver, hudson, phpunit, trac

I am looking for a web server where I can place my SVN repository on.

The solution should have a ticket tracking system like **TRAC**, and the ability to deploy to live from the server using a tool something like **Hudson** and have **PHPUnit** testing built-in on deployment.

Does anyone know where I can find such a thing?

I have found SVN servers, Hudson, etc. But all separate solutions, however I'm looking for something all on the same server package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ubersvn](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn) is closest to what you want, but nothing is an all-in-one package. You should try to combine the pieces yourself, you'll learn good stuff and get a solution that fits perfectly to your needs. All these things do just that anyway, take individual pieces and combine them to make a whole that's better than the pieces.

Ubersvn has an '[app store](http://www.wandisco.com/uberapps/apps)' including Jenkins for build and what deployment it offers, but you'll still have to [configure it](http://jenkins-php.org/) for PHPUnit (and [Clover](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clover+PHP+Plugin))

Answer (score 1):

I am running Apache web server on a Linux server and within that environment running Subversion and Trac.  Here is an article to get you started [Using Subversion under Apache](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configuring-apache-for-subversion-use/5902186)

Here is an article for Debian [using Subversion under Apache in Debian](http://www.debuntu.org/2006/05/20/54-how-to-subversion-svn-with-apache2-and-dav/)

Comment: Does your answer include the holistic solution? Would it include the deployment using Hudson and have unit testing included?